# Can you add custom styling to bsCollapsePanel in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Here is an example of a shiny app using bsCollapsePanel but it only shows 6 different possible colors. Can I choose a different color and font size and text alignment? I have tried unsuccessfully to do it in my .css file but I feel like that is maybe the way to go?

```
library(shinyBS)

shinyApp(
  ui =
    fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(HTML("This button will open Panel 1 using updateCollapse."),
                     actionButton("p1Button", "Push Me!"),
                     selectInput("styleSelect", "Select style for Panel 1",
                                 c("default", "primary", "danger", "warning", "info", "success"))
        ),
        mainPanel(
          bsCollapse(id = "collapseExample", open = "Panel 2",
                     bsCollapsePanel("Panel 1", "This is a panel with just text ",
                                     "and has the default style. You can change the style in ",
                                     "the sidebar.", style = "info"),
                     bsCollapsePanel("Panel 2", "This panel has a generic plot. ",
                                     "and a 'success' style.", plotOutput("genericPlot"), style = "success")
          )
        )
      )
    ),
  server =
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$genericPlot <- renderPlot(plot(rnorm(100)))
      observeEvent(input$p1Button, ({
        updateCollapse(session, "collapseExample", open = "Panel 1")
      }))
      observeEvent(input$styleSelect, ({
        updateCollapse(session, "collapseExample", style = list("Panel 1" = input$styleSelect))
      }))
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(shinyBS)

shinyApp(
  ui =
    fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(HTML("This button will open Panel 1 using updateCollapse."),
                     actionButton("p1Button", "Push Me!"),
                     selectInput(
                         "styleSelect", "Get some rainbow colors for Panel 1", 
                         c('Violet',
                           'Indigo',
                           'Blue'  ,
                           'Green' ,
                           'Yellow',
                           'Orange',
                           'Red')
                    )
        ),
        mainPanel(
          uiOutput("panel_style"),
          bsCollapse(id = "collapseExample", open = "Panel 2",
                     bsCollapsePanel("Panel 1", "This is a panel with just text ",
                                     "and has the default style. You can change the style in ",
                                     "the sidebar.", style = "info"),
                     bsCollapsePanel("Panel 2", "This panel has a generic plot. ",
                                     "and a 'success' style.", plotOutput("genericPlot"), style = "success")
          )
        )
      )
    ),
  server =
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$genericPlot <- renderPlot(plot(rnorm(100)))
      observeEvent(input$p1Button, ({
        updateCollapse(session, "collapseExample", open = "Panel 1")
      }))
      
      color_font_map <- reactive({
          switch (input$styleSelect,
                  'Violet' = c('148 0 211', "10px", "left"),
                  'Indigo' = c('75 0 130', "14px", "left"),
                  'Blue'   = c('0 0 255', "18px", "center"),
                  'Green'  = c('0 255 0', "22px", "center"),
                  'Yellow' = c('255 255 0', "26px", "center"),
                  'Orange' = c('255 127 0', "30px", "right"),
                  'Red'    = c('255 0 0', "34px", "right")
          )
      })
      
      output$panel_style <- renderUI({
          
          tags$style(HTML(glue::glue(.open = "@{", .close = "}@",
          '
          #collapseExample div[value^="Panel 1"] > .panel-heading {
              color: rgb(@{color_font_map()[1]}@);
              background-color: rgb(@{color_font_map()[1]}@ / 20%);
              text-align: @{color_font_map()[3]}@;

          }
          #collapseExample div[value^="Panel 1"] .panel-title {
              font-size: @{color_font_map()[2]}@;
          }
          '
          )))
      })
    }
)
```

The way here is render the style dynamically from server where we have a mapping `reactive` to store the values in a vector. First value is the RGB color, second is font size, third is alignment. Background color is 20% transparency of text color.

The key is to find the correct CSS selector. I recommend you learn more from: https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you @lz100! Is there a way to set one of those colors directly in the bsCollapsePanel so that the panel can start out that color when the app is launched instead of it needing to be selected after the fact? Like if the left side panel wasn't even there. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AlyssaAllsop The simplest way from current code is to set the `color_font_map` to the value you want without `input$styleSelect`, like `switch ("Violet", ...`